# "Pardon me" when someone says something remarkable?

Tags: phrase-usage

I always thought you could use *pardon me* (or *I beg your pardon* if you want to be more formal) in the sense "Do you really mean that [typically something quite offensive]? I disagree.", e.g.,

- You were really rude towards Alice yesterday.
- Pardon me!?!?!? [Alice got what she deserved]

but no such meaning is listed on https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pardon_me

I have also always thought *excuse me* could be used quite interchangeably with *pardon me* in this sense.

Have I misunderstood something here?

In other languages I speak expressions for apologies can be used like this.

Comment: Yes, and not every single usage can be in a dictionary. It's the same as excuse me.

Comment: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pardon meaning #2. In your sentence, it's more like "Really? Are you serious?" - their statement surprised (or even offended) you.